# Looping with ES6 Template

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why the browser complains about } missing in Template ?

Update: answer is ";" so the browser said something wrong.
Update2: still doesn't work because foreach returns nothing.
Update3: I know about using map that's not my question.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="test">
      </div>

      <script>

          let names = ["a", "b"];
          template = `<table>
          ${names.forEach(name => {
              `<TR><TD>${name}</TD></TR>`}
            );
          }
          </table>
          `;
          let div = document.getElementById("test");
          div.innerHTML = template;
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Because you're missing a } inside your template literal. At the end.,

Comment: @senojoeht that's my question: I can't see any missing } inside my template literal

Comment: @csmckelvey I count I have 2 of each

Comment: Because you have an extra `;`. You'll next find that it doesn't do what you want it to do, but i think that's a separate question.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's the semicolon

Comment: Couldn't delete my comment fast enough apparently... the thing was there for like 5 seconds and got 2 replies...

Comment: @senojoeht yes thanks that's it (though it still doesn't work but not same question)

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this,

```
let names = ["a", "b"];
template = `<table>
            ${names.map(name => `<TR><TD>${name}</TD></TR>`)}
          </table>
          `;
console.log(template);
let div = document.getElementById("test");
div.innerHTML = template;
```

`forEach` method does not return anything. You should `map` since you are expecting an array to be returned.

Comment: I know I can use map. But here I want to understand why the syntax with foreach doesn't work

Comment: Ah OK, but map returns also "," this complicates thing as I'll have to get rid off "," :( is there really any way to use foreach ?

Comment: .join('') would remove the comma.

Comment: I know but still I want to know if there is a way with foreach or if it is really impossible :)

Comment: You can use `forEach` but then you need to manually `push` into an array and use that array. Check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v79qs2w9/2/)